# Do we need something in between an answer and a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, etiquette

Take a look at [this question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14400/1095)

I submitted an answer.  Shalom then submitted an interesting, relevant, additional point, that was meant to enhance my answer.

Someone commented that his answer was not an answer at all, and that what he wrote belonged in the comment section to my answer.

This is only the latest example.  Often times, many of us will agree on an answer given, and want to add additional information to enhance that point.

I view this as more significant than a comment, but not quite enough to be its own answer.

Would it be possible to create some kind of "sub-answer" functionality?

Alternatively, should someone who wants to add an additional point, simply edit the existing answer, and insert their point at the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

A pattern I've seen sometimes is to post the information in a comment and give the answerer some time to edit it into his post himself.  I think that's a good approach.

If the poster doesn't edit the information in after some reasonable amount of time (whatever that is), then if others have up-voted the comment I would go ahead and edit it in.  If not, I probably wouldn't -- just because *I* think my comment is a great enhancement doesn't mean anyone else does.  (Note: I wrote that paragraph without referring to the particular case you cited; it's a general comment about how I try to behave.)

Comment: "it's a general comment" or a general _answer_? :)

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's a comment about how I behave in general and how I've seen some others behave, and is not at all a comment on the specific question that WIll linked in his question.